# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: list object has no element 1

Tags: json, jinja2

```
"artists": {
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=Hozier&type=artist&offset=0&limit=20",
        "items": [
          {
            "images": [
              {
                "height": 640,
                "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/2e4114631a20bd71903bc335b88f872afdce9a33",
                "width": 640
              },
              {
                "height": 320,
                "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/4d4be818dc98d47b9086ecff8ec4883902781070",
                "width": 320
              },
              {
                "height": 160,
                "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/c181b6184e82bd7f8411d97b87e4f1daa1bbbbb8",
                "width": 160
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
```

I'm trying to access the value of the url key in the second dict using jinja2, the problem is that every time i run the webpage it gives me a status code `500` and upon closer look in the terminal it gives me a `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: list object has no element 1` but that doesn't make sense to me since it prints `{{value[1]}}` just fine. The issue arises when i try to loop through the keys and values of that dict.

The following is my jinja2 code. if you can point out what i'm doing wrong or what i'm missing here that would be truly appreciated.

```
{% if q_type == "artist" %}
    {% for record in results['artists']['items'] %}
        {% for key, value in record.items() %}
            
            {% if key == "images" %}
                {% for k, v in value[1].items() %}
                    {% if k == "url" %}
                        {{info.append(v) or ""}}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```